# HTML input only accept 0-9(Number in English) and ০-৯ (Number in Bengali)?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a html input field . I want to allow only `[0-9]` (digits in English) and `[০-৯]` (digits in Bengali)

If I used `type='number'` then it only support `[0-9]` not support `[০-৯]`.

If I used `type='text'` then it support any type of character

**Any Idea please?**

Comment: Input pattern description: https://html.com/attributes/input-pattern/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to completely disable the user from inserting not numeric digits, then you should overwrite the `keydown` event and prevent it if the key isn't right.
You can also add an event for paste to only allow paste events that only contain the allowed characters.

```js
var allowedKeys = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9",
  "ARROWRIGHT", "ARROWLEFT", "TAB", "BACKSPACE", "DELETE", "HOME", "END", "০", "১", "২", "৩", "৪", "৫", "৬", "৭", "৮", "৯"
];

if (document.readyState === "complete") onLoad();
else addEventListener("load", onLoad);

function onLoad() {
  document.querySelectorAll("input.numeric").forEach(function(input) {
    input.addEventListener("keydown", onInputKeyDown);
    input.addEventListener("paste", onInputPaste);
  });
}

function onInputKeyDown(event) {
  if (!allowedKeys.includes(event.key.toUpperCase()) && !event.ctrlKey) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

function onInputPaste(event) {
  var clipboardData = event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  if (/^[0-9০-৯]+$/g.test(clipboardData.getData("Text"))) return;
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="numeric">
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working pure HTML-CSS solution.
Please note that text can still be entered into the input element but the browser can handle the validation.

It is a trade-off you need to make to support multilingual-input box.

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 2px dashed red;
}

input:valid {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label for="numberBox">Enter a number</label>
  <input type="text" name="numberBox" pattern="[০-৯0-9]" title="Numbers only">
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's fine but is there any way of preventing others character also?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked `[০-৯0-9]` pattern but seems not working. So, by using `javascript's` `onkeydown` event you may achieve your goal.

```js
function validateNumber(event)
{
    var unicode = event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.charCode;

    /* For Numbers. */
    if ((unicode >= 48 && unicode <= 57) || (unicode >= 96 && unicode <= 105)) {
     return true;
    }

    /* For other keys that might allowed like [Backspace]. */

    /*
        8:  Backspace
        9:  Tab
        27: Escape
        35: End
        36: Home
        37: Left Arrow
        39: Right Arrow
        45: Insert
        46: Delete
    */
    var allowedKeys = [8, 9, 27, 35, 36, 37, 39, 45, 46];

    return (allowedKeys.indexOf(unicode) >= 0);
}
```

```html
Input: <input type="text" onkeydown="return validateNumber(event);">
```

Hopefully may it will help someone !

Comment: It working fine only for `[0-9]` . How I can get `[০-৯]` also ?

Comment: @HelalUddin Either you can add `keyCode` for `[০-৯]` or let me know so I will add it !

Comment: Thanks a lot. `keyCode` for all Bengali letters are shown me as `231` when I `alert(event.keyCode)` but I need to allow only number not any other alphabet .

Comment: Can you please alert `charCode` and let me know.

Comment: `charCode` shown me as `0` for any Bengali character

Answer (score 1):

To construct the JS regex pattern, first see [Bengali Unicode Charts](https://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0980.pdf).

> **09E6** `০` BENGALI DIGIT ZERO
>   09E7 `১` BENGALI DIGIT ONE
>   09E8 `২` BENGALI DIGIT TWO
>   09E9 `৩` BENGALI DIGIT THREE
>   09EA `৪` BENGALI DIGIT FOUR
>   09EB `৫` BENGALI DIGIT FIVE
>   09EC `৬` BENGALI DIGIT SIX
>   09ED `৭` BENGALI DIGIT SEVEN
>   09EE `৮` BENGALI DIGIT EIGHT
>   **09EF** `৯` BENGALI DIGIT NINE

For matching [Unicode in JavaScript](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#codepoint) `\uXXXX` notation can be used. To match the wanted range together with `\d` [for](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `[0-9]`, all can be put into a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and quantified with `+` for [one or more](https://javascript.info/regexp-quantifiers).

```
[\d\u09E6-\u09EF]+
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/j3QpgV/1/) (if using with JS functions, might want to [anchor](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) the pattern)

---

**Demo 1**: Validation with [HTML input **pattern attribute**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp)

```html
<!-- input pattern test-->
<form>
  <input type="text" value="1234567890০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯" pattern="[\d\u09E6-\u09EF]+">
  <input type="submit" value="check">
</form>
```

---

**Demo 2**: JS validation with [**RegExp `test()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

```js
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function(event)
{
  if(!/^[\d\u09E6-\u09EF]+$/g.test(document.getElementById('myinput').value))
  {
    alert('Please enter just Latin and Bengali digits!');
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<form id="myform">
  <input id="myinput" type="text">
  <input type="submit" value="test">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pattern` attribute for html5

**EDIT**
pattern attribute changes input validity. You can test validity with the following example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="username" pattern="[0-9]">

    <script>
    var input = document.getElementById('username');

    input.addEventListener('input', function(event){
        console.log(input.validity.valid);
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

to restrict input you can just change input value in listener.

[Here](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html5-form-validation-with-the-pattern-attribute--cms-25145) is an example for input validation with pattern attribute.

Comment: I have tried according to your provide links but this pattern attribute don't restrict other character . ``` pattern="[0-9০-৯]" ``` it support ```abc``` also

Comment: @nickzoum removed

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regular expression. ^[০-৯0-9]+$
 input type should be text as well

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
         <body>    

         <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
          <input type="text" id="numeric">
          <p id="demo"></p>

          <script>
             function myFunction() {
               var str = document.getElementById('numeric').value;
               var reg = new RegExp('^[০-৯0-9]+$');
               var result = reg.test(str);
               document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = result;
            }
         </script>

       </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this untested OneLiner

```
<input type="number" onkeypress="return /[0-9০-৯]/i.test(event.key)">
```